# redirect Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

i need help on redirect codeigniter.When I go to the login page (redirect) it can not switch to the login page. 
this is the page MY_Controller.When I switch to the login page it does not understand

```
  private function _check_login()
{
    $controller = $this->uri->rsegment('1');
    $controller = strtolower($controller);

    $login = $this->session->userdata('login');
    //neu ma chua dang nhap,ma truy cap 1 controller khac login
    if(!$login && $controller != 'C_Login')
    {
        redirect(admin_url('C_Login'));
    }
    //neu ma admin da dang nhap thi khong cho phep vao trang login nua.
    if($login && $controller == 'C_Login')
    {
        redirect(admin_url('C_Home'));
    }
}
```

thanks very much

Comment: What does `admin_url()` do? Please show its code.

Comment: <?php 
function admin_url($url=''){
 return base_url('admin/'.$url);
}
This is function admin_url(). I do not understand why it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are loading the URL helper in your autoload.php under config folder

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

you can load multiple helpers too like array('url','file')
or in the controller where you need

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: yes,I checked all but still did not work. Thanks for answering